# Non-UEFI computer can't see UEFI Hard Drive

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, bios

Long story short I had a computer, (Windows 8,UEFI, Samsung 840 EVO SSD) system.  I spilled coffee on that system and am sending it off to be repaired.  I wanted to make sure the hard drive was okay, so I put it into my older laptop which is from the pre-UEFI (Windows 7, circa 2011) era.  During the booting of the old computer, it complained it couldn't find the Hard Drive.  My question is,

"Is it normal that a non-UEFI system can't see a UEFI'd hard drive"?

I don't have another UEFI biosed system, so I can't really test it to see if my hard drive is any good (and yes, I didn't back some stuff up that I desperately need =()

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a UEFI HDD; it's a GPT HDD with EFI drivers; UEFI is the firmware itself.  You cannot boot a hdd that uses GPT partitions if you don't have a computer a UEFI firmware.  A BIOS firmware cannot boot to the disk, only disks that use MBR partitions

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks Ram,  that's what I thought was happening,  I just didn't know how to flesh it out.